# Automation Anywhere: In PDF Integration, Extract Form Fields isn't working properly?

Tags: automation, automationanywhere

I'm using Extract Form Fields to get data from a PDF. But upon selecting the area where the desired text is located, the "Value" text area in the popup should be automatically populated with desired text, but that isn't the case. The "Value" field is staying blank.

Any idea what might be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

you need to check whether your PDF has handwritten content or it is a scanned file.
if your PDF does not satisfy above criteria you can easily automate your PDF using Automation anywhere by selecting the area. if your PDF is invoice or bill or any type of GST forms better to use IQ Bot.